# Even out fluctuating exposure on old video

Tags: color-correction, color

I'm trying to restore this old Charlie Chaplin snippet:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyNU3.jpg

I have trouble with the exposure of the clip, it fluctuates from brighter to darker. I want the exposure have an even consistency over the entirety of the clip.

How would you go about fixing this? I'm new to video editing and am trying to find right words to google. I have tried de-flickering plugins with no success, as it seems to be mainly designed for time-lapses or high frame rate flickering.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [GBDeflicker](http://granitebaysoftware.com/Products/ProductGBD.aspx) to see if it improves the footage.
They have a free demo. It is designed for smoothing out time-lapses (and is good at this), but it might work on archive video?